Android Studio / How can I set 1 image on splash screen on API 31?
Is it possible set one image on splash screen?
I want to set only one image because the app icon, app name and brand name are already in the image.
So I don't have to set background color or icon.
I used splash screen api, but I can't float only one image. I could only see the white background and the app icon.
I searched a lot, but I couldn't find a solution.
I'm not a android developer and I'm in charge of it temporarily, so I don't know well :(
Thank you.
I have a image for splash screen, xml file for splash screen in drawable folder.
I set new style for splash (I read android developer guide and followed exactly the same way)
<style name="Theme.SplashTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
    <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@drawable/splash_image</item>
    <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@null</item>
    <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.AppTheme</item>
</style>

It doesn't work the way I think it does. It shows our app icon and background color
I also tried to set the image in item name = windowbackground
like this
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_image</item>


The style name and parent style name seems to be the same "Theme.SplashTheme". Can you recheck the parent theme? Also can you check if the theme is applied to the Activity in androidmanifest file?

@Pavan oh, I asked a question after I changed it, but I accidentally posted the code before the change. And I added the theme in androidmanifest. I'll try it all over again.
